# Prolog unification of predicates as argument

Tags: parameters, prolog, predicate

That's probably an easy one!

I have a predicate in a rule parameter. I query the rule with a fact that makes the predicate true. I'd expect SWI-Prolog to apply the predicate to the fact, infer it's truth value (true) and return accoridngly (true). But I do get false.

My facts:

```
key(cMaj).
key(aMin).
chord(key(X)).
```

My query:

```
?- chord(cMaj).
```

Because `key(cMaj)` is true, I would expect Prolog to make this inference and return true. I do get false. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: `chord(key(X)).` is a rule that will succeed no matter what `X` is since it's a variable. You're saying, "The chord of key X is true". So `chord(key(cMaj))` would be true. So would `chord(key(fred)).` However, `chord(cMaj)` doesn't match any of your facts or your rule, so it fails. What is it that you want to say, or what do you want `chord(X)` to mean? Do you really mean "If X is a key, then X is a chord?" If so, that's, `chord(X) :- key(X).` (*`X` is a chord if `X` is a key.*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only an expanded version of what @mbratch wrote in his comment. But maybe it can help some too:

In Prolog, we can read `chord(cMaj)` to say "C Major is a chord". To find out what Prolog thinks your definition of `chord/1` says, query it with a free variable:

```
?- chord(X).
X = key(_G1419).
```

Prolog reads your definition of `chord/1` to be a description of a complex prolog term: "the term `key(_)` is a chord". This is how pattern matching with terms works. `chord(X)` is true so long as `X` is unfieid with something of the form `key(_)`, just as `list_head([Head|Tail], Head)` is true if `Head` unifies with the first element in a list and `Tail` unifies with the rest.

Your definition of `key/1` says that "`cMaj` and `cMin` are keys" (it is also naming terms--in this case, atoms). To get `chord(cMaj)` to turn out true, we need to define `chord/1` such that `chord(X)` is true if `key(X)` is true:

```
chord(X) :- key(X).
```

`key/1` now appears as a term to be evaluated, and `X` is unified with `cMaj` or `aMin`. This effectively establishes `chord/1` as a synonym for `key/1`: they each describe the same object.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration! The example I gave is a minimal one. It is actually `chord/7` - I just left it out the boring bits here.
So when/why should one use a complex term like `chord(key(X))`? I thought to have read this structure can be used to simulate what other languages could call named parameters? All I wanted was to make my `chord/7` more readable...